# How to get dictionary keys and values if both keys are in two separated dictionaries?

Tags: python, dictionary

I would like to get a new dictionary with keys only if both dictionaries have those keys in them, and then get the values of the second one.

```
# example:

Dict1 = {'A':3, 'B':5, 'C':2, 'D':5}
Dict2 = {'B':3, 'C':1, 'K':5}

# result--> {'B':3, 'C':1}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a dictionary comprehension:

```
>>> {k:v for k, v in Dict2.items() if k in Dict1}
{'B': 3, 'C': 1}
```

Answer (score 1):

Or use `filter`:

```
>>> dict(filter(lambda x: x[0] in Dict1, Dict2.items()))
{'B': 3, 'C': 1}
>>>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just another solution, doesn't use comprehension. This function loops through the keys `k` in `Dict1` and tries to add `Dict2[k]` to a new dict which is returned at the end. I think the try-except approach is "pythonic".

```
def shared_keys(a, b):
    """
    returns dict of all KVs in b which are also in a
    """
    shared = {}
    for k in a.keys():
        try:
            shared[k] = b[k]
        except:
            pass
    return shared

Dict1 = {'A':3, 'B':5, 'C':2, 'D':5}
Dict2 = {'B':3, 'C':1, 'K':5}
print(shared_keys(Dict1, Dict2))

# >>> {'B': 3, 'C': 1}
```